# understanding typescript inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, typescript

My question is inspired from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32202625/492258)

This is typescript inheritance code

```
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    __.prototype = b.prototype;
    d.prototype = new __();
};
```

and I simplified version to this version

```
function extend(Destination, Base) {
    function Hook() { this.constructor = Destination; }
    Hook.prototype = Base.prototype;
    var hook = new Hook();
    Destination.prototype = hook;
};
```

and I draw graphical represantation inspired from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9959727/492258):

[image]

Could you confirm or correct ghaphical representation?
I especially did not understand this part:

```
function Hook() { this.constructor = Destination; }
```

And could you tell me how inheritance work with arguments and accompanied example

Answer (score 1):

It it's any help, I've commented each line to illustrate what it does, based on the current `__extends` function (it's changed slightly from your example)

```
var extend = function (subType, superType) {

    // Copy superType's own (static) properties to subType
    for (var property in superType) {
        if (superType.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            subType[p] = superType[p];
        }
    }

    // Create a constructor function and point its constructor at the subType so that when a new ctor() is created, it actually creates a new subType.
    function ctor() {
        this.constructor = subType;
    }

    if(superType === null) {

        // Set the subType's prototype to a blank object.
        subType.prototype = Object.create(superType);

    } else {

        // set the ctor's prototype to the superType's prototype (prototype chaining)
        ctor.prototype = superType.prototype;

        // set the subType's prototype to a new instance of ctor (which has a prototype of the superType, and whos constructor will return a new instance of the subType)
        subType.prototype = new ctor();
    }
};
```

Note that `__extends` may change again in the very near future to include the use of `Object.setPrototypeOf(...);`

GitHub - [Change Class Inheritance Code](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12488)

Comment: Thanks for answer, you said `point its constructor at the subType so that when a new ctor() is created it actually creates a new subType.`. This is not clear to me.

Comment: for example, from chrome console: I declare subType`function subType(){this.a; alert(this.a);}` and ctor  `function ctor(){ this.constructor = subType}`, but when I do `new ctor()` it does not pop up alert

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak You also need to chain the prototypes. the constructor alone is not enough

Answer (score 0):

When I synthase my question and  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9343193/492258) and @series0ne's answer

Here is what I understand from typescript inheritance:

function ctor() does:

As in the linked answer:

```
Car.prototype.constructor = Car;
```

it is equivelant

```
subType.prototype.constructor = subType
```

which provides:

```
subType.constructor === subType  -> true
```

for

```
ctor.prototype = superType.prototype;
subType.prototype = new ctor();
```

it is equivalent

```
Car.prototype = new Vehicle(true, true);
```

which ensures

```
subType.prototype = new superType();
```